# Which is more fundamental: Python functions or Python object-methods?

Tags: python, function, object

I am trying to get a conceptual understanding of the nature of Python functions and methods. I get that functions are actually objects, with a method that is called when the function is executed. But is that function-object method actually another function?

For example:

```
def fred():
    pass
```

If I look at `dir(fred)`, I see it has an attribute named `__call__`. But `dir(fred.__call__)` *also* has an attribute named `__call__`. So does `fred.__call__.__call__` and so on. The ids of this chain of `__call__` objects suggest they are all distinct. Are they really objects or is this some low-level trick of the interpreter?

Which is more fundamental: functions or object-methods?

Comment: The ids of the call object suggest they're generated as requested: sometimes I see duplicates at different levels, and sometimes I see different ids at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is more fundamental: functions
>   or object-methods?

I think the best answer might be "neither".  See the [Execution model](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html) part of the Python reference, where it refers to "blocks".  This is what actually gets executed.   The `__call__` thing you were getting hung up on in the infinite search for an end is just a wrapper which knows how to execute the code block (see the various `func_xxx` attributes of your function instead, with the actual bytecode being stored as `func_code`).

Also relevant, the [Function definitions](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) section, which refers to "a function object [being] (a wrapper around the executable code for the function)".  Lastly, there's the term [callable](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls), which might also be an answer to "which is more fundamental?"

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: both are fundamental, `.__call__()` on functions is just a virtual trick.

---

The rest of this answer is a bit complicated.  You don't have to understand it, but I find the subject interesting.  Be warned that I'm going to present a series of lies, progressively fixing them.

### Long answer

At the most fundamental level, Python can be said to have just 2 operations:

- attribute access: `obj.attr`
- function call: `callable(args)`

Method calls - `obj.method(args)` - are not fundamental.  They consist of 2 steps: fetching the attribute `obj.method` (which gives a callable "bound method" object) and calling that with `args`.

Other operators are defined in terms of them.  E.g. `x + y` tries [`x.__add__(y)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__), falling back to other similar combinations if that doesn't work.

### Infinitely Long Answer?

So far so good.  But calling and attribute access themselves are also defined in terms of [`obj.__call__(args)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) and [`obj.__getattribute__(name)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)?!?
Is it turtles all the way down?!?

The trick is that operations on an *object* are defined by calling methods of its *type*: `type(obj).__call__(obj, args)` and `type(obj).__getattribute__(obj, name)`.  Which BTW means that I lied to you, and there is a third fundamental operation:

- getting the type of an object: `type(obj)`

OK, this is still not helpful.  `type(obj).__call__(...)` still involves an attribute access and a call, so this should continue ad infinitum?  The rub is that eventually you hit a *builtin* type - usually a function, `object` or `type` - and for them attribute access and function calls *are* fundamental.

So when you call a instance of a custom class, that's implemented through its `__call__` method indeed.  But its `__call__` method is probably a normal function - which can be called directly.  End of mystery.

Similarly about `__getattribute__` - you can provide it to *define* attribute access for your class, but the class itself implement attribute access fundamentally (unless it has a custom *metaclass*).

### The Curtain in Front of the Man

So why does even a function has a `fred.__call__` method?  Well that's just smoke and mirrors that Python pulls to blur the difference between builtin types and custom classes.  This method exists on all callable objects, but calling a normal function doesn't have to go through it - functions are fundamentally callable.

Similarly, all objects have `obj.__getattribute__` and `obj.__class__`, but for built-in types it just *exposes* the fundamental operations instead of *defining* it.

### Small Print

The first claim that Python had 2 fundamental operations was actually a complete lie.  Technically, all Python operators have a "fundamental" operation at the C level, exposed for consistency through a method, and custom classes can redefine these operations through similar methods.

But the story I told you could have been true, and it reduces the question its center: why  `.__call__()` and `.__getattribute__()` are not an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically a Python answer, but at the lowest level the processor understands only actions and variables.  From that we extrapolate functions, and from variables and functions we extrapolate objects.  So from a low-level programming perspective I'd say that the more fundamental thing is the function.

That's not necessarily true of Python in the Pythonic sense, and is probably a good example of why it's not always beneficial to look deeply into the implementation of the language as a user of it. :) Thinking of a function as an object is certainly the better answer in Python itself.

At first I thought your calls were tracking into the Python library, but the .call method has the same properties as any other method.  Thus it's recursively exploring itself, I think, having played with the python CLI for a few minutes; I think that is a painful way of exploring the architecture and while not necessarily a bug a property of how Python handles objects under the covers. :)